# Permission Denied when trying to write on a TPU VM foler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sdk

I use Cloud SDK to connect to my TPU VM, but I am getting Permission Denied error when trying to write on a folder in the vm.

How can I fix this please!

Comment: Hi, can you paste the exact commands and failure message?

Comment: Thanks, last night I added root when ssh on the vm and it worked. Do I need to edit my question with the solution?

Comment: Awesome! I'd recommend you to answer your own question, so people who faces the same issue can refer to this in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use this command:

```
sudo vi [filename]
```

Then, change to Insert Mode and save.
This works for me, but you may need to assure that you are connected to the TPU VM.